# Example of Match.expand usage

Tags: python, regex

What is an example usage of [`Match.expand`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.expand) ? It doesn't give any examples in the python docs (which is the first I've heard of the method), and only states:

> **Match.expand(template)**
>
> Return the string obtained by doing backslash substitution on the template string template, as done by the sub() method.

How would this actually be used and how could it be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find more explanations and examples here:

[match.expand](http://xahlee.info/python/python_regex_match_object.html)

In general:

it allows you to expand the match you have found and modify its' prefix